# how to redirect to another page during a ajax call

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, servlets

I have a simple login page and I am using Ajax to check the user credentials.
if true it should redirect to another page, else it should throw an error message.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function btnSignIn(){
      var uName = document.getElementById("uName").value;
      var pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
       $.ajax({
           url:   "/orgNgo/SignIn",
           type: "POST",
           data: {
               "uName" : uName,
               "pass" : pass
           }  ,
           success:function() {
               //... your other code
               //location.reload(); //reload the page on the success
               document.getElementById("lblError").innerHTML="Error";
           }  

       });
  }
  </script>
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>
            UserName:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="username" name="uName"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <label style="visibility: hidden;">required</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>
            Password:
            </td>
            <td>
            <input type="text" id="password" name="pass"/>
            </td>
            <td>
            <label style="visibility: hidden;">required</label>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            <input type="button" onclick="btnSignIn()"  value="Submit"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
         <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
            Not a member yet? <a href="/orgNgo/SignUp">SignUp</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Servlet code

```
    if(repeatUsername){//if user name and password matches it comes to this loop
                    stmt.close();
                    c.close();
                    session.setAttribute("lib", uName);
  request.getRequestDispatcher("/user/UserHome.jsp").forward(request,response);
                     //not working
                }
                else{

                    String loginError = "UserName or Password is wrong";
                     request.setAttribute("loginError", loginError);
                    response.setContentType("text/plain");
                    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
                    response.getWriter().write(String.valueOf(loginError));
    //not working
                }
```

Here if the user credentials are true the page is not getting redirected. when I debugged the code I found that it is reflecting in the console. And if the user credentials doesn't match it loginError String isn't getting passed to the success function of Ajax. 
I'm practising Ajax for a week but usually it would be just jsp to servlet but here I'm stuck because its a two way thing.

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Comment: You need to do the navigation job in JS side instead.

Comment: Yes I could do like this at servlet response.getWriter().write("1"); and then I can check at js success function if responseText is 1 i can redirect using window.location.assign("user/UserHome.jsp"); but i can't pass variable using session

Comment: If you ask and explain the weird "can't" in detail, you may get the right solution to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
success: function() {
    window.location = "another page";
}
```

will redirect to another page.
And it is up to you to check credencial

Comment: yes but how to pass values with that usually we pass values using request.setAttribute("firstName", registration.getfName()); which isn't working when I do like that

Comment: Don't know well jsp but you can surely pass variable by get

Comment: Okay thank you anyways. For now I passed it to another Servlet and I using session to get values.